# Parse Response via Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I'd like to ask you for a help.
I have the following output:

```
{
   'ActivationId': '24d8bac5-b849-42b2-b996-ca15fd829826', 
   'ActivationCode': 'jLu1oMmFGhZ/HQFGPr9P',
   'ResponseMetadata': {
      'RequestId': '7fc216f9-4c62-4b49-a17d-57c865f439ec', 
      'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 
      'HTTPHeaders': {
         'server': 'Server', 
         'date': 'Mon, 30 Aug 2021 09:58:39 GMT',
         'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 
         'content-length': '95', 
         'connection': 'keep-alive', 
         'x-amzn-requestid': '7fc216f9-4c62-4b49-a17d-57c865f439ec'
      }, 
      'RetryAttempts': 0
   }
}
```

I would need to parse such output, in order to get only 2 values and use them as variables for further processing:

```
id=24d8bac5-b849-42b2-b996-ca15fd829826
code=jLu1oMmFGhZ/HQFGPr9P
```

May I ask you for a help how to achieve it via Python?

Many thanks in advance
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the following:-

```
output_dict = {'ActivationId': '24d8bac5-b849-42b2-b996-ca15fd829826', 'ActivationCode': 'jLu1oMmFGhZ/HQFGPr9P', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '7fc216f9-4c62-4b49-a17d-57c865f439ec', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Mon, 30 Aug 2021 09:58:39 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '95', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': '7fc216f9-4c62-4b49-a17d-57c865f439ec'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

id = output_dict['ActivationId']
code = output_dict['ActivationCode']
```

you can use this code in a loop if you have multiple such responses.

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
response = {...}
id = response.get("ActivationID")
code = response.get("ActivationCode")
```

Or if it's raw json, then:

```
import json
raw_json = '{...}'
response = json.loads(raw_json)
id = response.get("ActivationID")
code = response.get("ActivationCode")
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you

```
for key,val in var.items():
    if 'ActivationId' in key or 'ActivationCode' in key:
        print(key,val)
```

result

```
ActivationId 24d8bac5-b849-42b2-b996-ca15fd829826
ActivationCode jLu1oMmFGhZ/HQFGPr9P
```